# Rails 3.2 ActiveRecord Database Field Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1, coffeescript

I have a rails 3.2 application where I have a table called menu_items.  My rails application barks when I read data that has an apostrophe in it (ex "Devil's food cake"). I am able to input the field however reading it is a different story.  My application works perfectly as long as I delete the record with the apostrophe.  My view is an ajax form where I remotely retrieve the record.  My schema is below.

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| description | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| price       | decimal(8,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| serves      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| measurement | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at  | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at  | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| section_id  | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| position    | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Following is the error I receive when trying to edit the record within my application.

```
ActionView::Template::Error (SyntaxError: reserved word "class" can't be assigned on line 343):
    1: $('#edit_form').empty()
    2: $('#available_menu_items_container').empty()
    3: $('#available_menu_items_container').html('<%= render :partial => "menu_item" %>')
    4: $('.new_menu').hide()
  app/views/menus/edit.js.coffee:1:in `_app_views_menus_edit_js_coffee__4311426478414483561_70345298165400'
  app/controllers/menus_controller.rb:33:in `edit'
```

Comment: Show us verbatim response from that ajax call.

Comment: You're almost certainly forgetting to properly quote/escape something somewhere. What does your `edit.js.coffee` look like?

Answer (score 1):

According to the error message, you're setting an attribute called `class` somewhere

```
ActionView::Template::Error (SyntaxError: reserved word "class" can't be assigned on line 343):
```

Look at line 343 (I think in your view) for something like

Perhaps you're setting a CSS class?

Really weird that an apostrophe would effect that - I think removing the record with the apostrophe is just hiding this bug rather than solving the issue.